# localhost refusing connection in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, configuration-files

I am learning WCF(C#) while I am hosting WCF using console application. It is showing no errors but when I type http://localhost:8080/ in browser browser saying it is refusing connnection. Please provide me solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6wmw.png)

my code in configuration file is given below

```
    <services>
  <service name="MyService.MyWService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyWService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyWService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Add `http://` before localhost

Comment: tried it but no use

Comment: I found the problem. It is becuase I was hosting wcf in console application and I am not keeping it alive by using console.readline() command that is why localhost is not working. It was staying alive for few milliseconds only

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to the browser being unable to locate the website localhost. you should visit localhost addresses using the following format.

`http[s]://localhost:<port number>`

you can also view localhost addresses by visiting 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback address for your localhost.

`127.0.0.1:8080`